# ASP Text Box Mode Date Time setting Current DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

TextBox, Text mode set to DatetimeLocal

```
 <!--Date-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                <h4>Date</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="DateTimeLocal"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is my page_load Handler, setting current date time in textbox

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["user"] != null)
                {                    
                    txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                }
                else
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Current datetime not showing in textbox. . . 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to parse the date before assign it:

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm");
```