# How to populate an asp:textbox in TextMode="DateTimeLocal"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, textbox, datetime-format

In my ASP.Net app, I have a textbox set to be a datepicker:
`<asp:TextBox ID="uxDateTimeLocalTextbox" runat="server" TextMode="DateTimeLocal"></asp:TextBox>`

[image]

When the user enters the datetime, initially its a string and must be converted to DateTime format before I send it back to my SQL Server table (where that column is in datetime format):

```
DateTime dateTimeOriginalEmail = Convert.ToDateTime(uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text);
```

Now, I have created functionality that will do the reverse, and populate the textbox with a value stored in the SQL table. I would think that I need to take that value and convert it back to a string. So, I tried the below (no errors were thrown) but I don't see the textbox being populated with the value from my table. I am using this method on other textboxes and dropdowns and they work fine. Any suggestions on how to get this to work? (Note: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM)

```
uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text = ticketInfo.Rows[0]["DateTimeOriginalEmail"].ToString();
```

Comment: If you put a break on that code, is there a value coming from SQL to the dataset? I know, probably a stupid question, but sometimes the most important.

Comment: Hmmm, just checked the value at the break point. It comes back as "3/12/2019 3:06:00 PM" I wonder if I need to lop off those extra :00s?

Comment: You are probably right... try to format it to what it's expecting.

Comment: I just tried `DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ticketInfo.Rows[0]["DateTimeOriginalEmail"]);` and then `uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text = newDate.ToString("g");`. This returned "3/12/2019 3:06 PM". But it still would not populate the textbox.

Comment: Instead of using `.ToString()`, use `.ToShortDateString()` and see what you get.

Comment: That just returns "3/12/2019". And it still did not populate the textbox. I'm wondering if there is a method or mode other than `.Text` I need to use in order to get this in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm");

Comment: I'm finding that that works in Chrome, but in Firefox the T appears ... :'(

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:  (VB code but easy to change to C#)

```
If IsDate(dr("cnnReminder")) = True Then txtNoteReminderTS.Text = Format(dr("cnnReminder"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm")
```

ps. dr is a DataRow and cnnReminder a SQL DateTime

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854660/2939161 LEM2802 solved it!

txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm");